# Boost library linking error in Xcode

Tags: xcode, boost

1. Boost was installed and make by: `brew install boost`
2. Added the header path `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.53.0/include` to User Header Search Path
3. Added the library path `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.53.0/lib` to Library Search Path

main.cpp

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "test.cpp"

void test(){
    Test instance(true, 'm', 50, 17.89, "fuzhijie");
    stringstream binary_sstream; 
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive binary_oa(binary_sstream);
    binary_oa << instance;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

When I press CTRL+b, the following error message is shown:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::archive::basic_binary_oprimitive<boost::archive::binary_oarchive, char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::init()", referenced from:
      boost::archive::binary_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::binary_oarchive, char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::init(unsigned int) in main.o
  "boost::archive::basic_binary_oprimitive<boost::archive::binary_oarchive, char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::save(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      void boost::archive::save_access::save_primitive<boost::archive::binary_oarchive, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >(boost::archive::binary_oarchive&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in main.o
  "boost::archive::basic_binary_oprimitive<boost::archive::binary_oarchive, char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_binary_oprimitive(std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool)", referenced from:
      boost::archive::binary_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::binary_oarchive, char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::binary_oarchive_impl(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, unsigned int) in main.o
  "boost::archive::basic_binary_oprimitive<boost::archive::binary_oarchive, char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_binary_oprimitive()", referenced from:
      boost::archive::binary_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::binary_oarchive, char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~binary_oarchive_impl() in main.o
      boost::archive::binary_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::binary_oarchive, char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::binary_oarchive_impl(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, unsigned int) in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: `Boost.Serialization` is not a header-only library, you should link the binary (`-lserialization`).

Comment: I had added the libboost-serializtion-mt.dylib to the Link Binary with Librarys, if dont link, there is other error shown.

Comment: `dylib` is a dynamic library, you can't link it - it's being loaded at run-time. You should link its import library `boost-serialization-mt.a`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is maybe you have compiler gcc5 or gcc6. 
And your code has used different compile flag with your boost library.
Detail please read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33394934/converting-std-cxx11string-to-stdstring)

If you can recompile all incompatible libs you use, do it with compiler option

```
-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1
```

and then rebuild your project. If still can not link, add change project's makefile compiler option to 0.

```
-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0
```

======Update=======

The real solution should be install the new boost libraries (v1.62) for gcc6 or gcc5.